# handsontable's subproject rulejs: how to get the calculated value of a formula cell?

Tags: handsontable

rulejs subproject of handsontable is great. But I can't find anything that emulates the "paste special" of spreadsheets. So, if I write

```
afterOnCellMouseDown: function(r, c) {
    var x = hotdata[c['row']][c['col']];
    document.getElementById("valorCelCorrente").innerHTML = x;}
```

I get the formula, not the calculated value that the cell is displaying. Same happens with a manual copy & paste. 
A fiddle with example: https://jsfiddle.net/zota/j2a04w83/3/
Any clue? Thanks a lot
Julio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, but solved it with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074056/handsontable-save-formula-values).

Firstly you can use `hot.plugin.helper.cellValue('CELL REF')` to get the actual value, but when using getData() you're looking at the whole set. To solve this problem I basically iterated through the array replacing any formula cells with the value (I only needed columns up until 'K'):

```
var aCols = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K'];                   
var data = hot.getData();

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
        if(data[i][j].toString().indexOf('=') > -1){
            data[i][j] = hot.plugin.helper.cellValue (aCols[j] + (i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
BTW: googled it, but didn't find info about `.plugin.helper.cellValue ()` Are there any info? please...
tx again

Comment: That's really all I could see sorry. This was helpful too though - [https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Methods](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Methods)